# jQuery autocomplete not showing results in IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This works fine from Visual Studio (2012) but when I publish to IIS server, the "ac test" alert goes up but "Ams/GetAccounts" results are never returned.

```
    $("#Identity").autocomplete({
        source: '/Ams/GetAccounts',
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 1000,
        response: function (event, ui) {
            alert("ac test"); 
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                   // do something with selection
            }
            else {
                alert("Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I wasn't resolving the url properly for it to work in both VS and IIS. MVC apps should use the Url.Action helper, e.g. '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "AMS")', to get resolved properly in both environments.